# Error when sending DOCX to DocuSign REST API

Tags: docusignapi

I'm getting the following error when trying to send DOCX documents to docusign through the rest API
Until now it has worked just fine for almost a year. I've tested it with a variety of DOCX files and all of them return this error

```
"errorCode": "UNABLE_TO_CONVERT_DOCUMENT", 
"message": "System was unable to convert this document to a PDF. Unable to convert Document(afasf.docx) to a PDF. 
Error: UserId:********-****-*****-*****-*********** IPAddress:***.***.***.*** 
Source:ApiRESTv2:Could not submit Document to Conversion Server: EnvelopeId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 DocumentName:afasf.docx - 
SubmitCode: -10242\r\nCould not submit Document to Conversion Server: EnvelopeId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 DocumentName:afasf.docx - 
SubmitCode: -10242\r\nCould not submit Document to Conversion Server: EnvelopeId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 DocumentName:afasf.docx - 
SubmitCode: -10242\r\n"
```

Comment: 1. I would check the content-type to see if it matches application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document from StackOverflow article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212861/what-is-a-correct-mime-type-for-docx-pptx-etc

Comment: 2. I would always recommend posting the full json multipart request as I have seen far too many missing needed carriage returns and line feeds as well as headers below the bytes, vs after the boundary

Comment: 3. I prefer the following base64 for removing the issue of router inspection, etc but it is larger by about a 1/3. --AAA
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: file; filename="f4506t.pdf"; documentid=1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

Comment: Any chance you can update this and mark answered?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I look forward to your answers from above, but here is working example in base64 of a docx

I use this online tool for encoding, decoding files to/from base64  http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/Base64Encode/

**URI, Verb and Headers:**

```
POST /restapi/v2/accounts/225705/envelopes HTTP/1.1
Host: demo.docusign.net
X-DocuSign-Authentication: your info aka userid, password and integrator key
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=AAA
Accept: application/json
```

**Body of Post:**

```
--AAA
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Disposition: form-data

{
    "emailBlurb": "Test for basic docx",
    "emailSubject": "Test for docx",
    "status": "sent",
    "compositeTemplates": [
        {
            "inlineTemplates": [
                {

                    "sequence": "1",
                    "documents": [
                        {
                            "documentId": "1",
                            "name": "basic.docx"
                        }
                    ],
                    "recipients": {
                        "signers": [
                            {
                                "recipientId": "1",
                                "name": "Your Name",
                                "email": "youremail@yourdomain.com",
                                "defaultRecipient": "true",
                                "tabs": {
                                    "signHereTabs": [{
                                    "anchorString": "\\Signhere\\",
                                    "tabLabel": "Sign Here 1"
                                    }]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

--AAA
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
Content-Disposition: file; filename="basic.docx"; documentid=1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQDpURCwjQEAAMIFAAATAAgCW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLnhtbCCiBAIooAAC **[base64 truncated to meet StackOverflow Limit of 30000 since it was 33196 ]** FYAAGRvY1Byb3BzL2FwcC54bWxQSwUGAAAAAA0ADQBOAwAAtVgAAAAA

--AAA--
```

Comment: basic.docx contained the following text saved as a Microsoft Word Document:

Basic Document



---------------------
\\Signhere\\

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the file extension?

```
var doc = new docusign.Document();
var base64Doc = Buffer.from(fileBytes).toString('base64');
doc.documentBase64 = base64Doc;
doc.fileExtension = 'docx';
```